# cryptol: arithmetic with different width

Tags: cryptol

How to perform arithmetic with values of different widths ?
In verilog there is no problem xoring 2 bits with 8 bits but cryptol complains:

```
cryptol> let test(x: [2],y: [8]) = x ^ y

[error] at <interactive>:1:31--1:32:
  Type mismatch:
    Expected type: 2
    Inferred type: 8
```

My original problem:
I would like to rotate the bytes in a 64 bit value, with the number of bytes to shift depending on a two bit input. I struggle to get this working:

```
cryptol> let shift (v, s:[2]) = v >>> (s*16+8)
[error] at <interactive>:1:5--1:38:
Unsolved constraint:
2 >= 5
  arising from
  use of literal or demoted expression
  at <interactive>:1:33--1:35
```

In the interpreter I can remove the type specification of s and then it works however I need to get that working from a file and with s being really a 2 bit value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `^` is:

```
Cryptol> :t (^)
(^) : {a} (Logic a) => a -> a -> a
```

Note that it requires both arguments to be exactly the same. You're getting the type-error because `[2]` is not the same as `[8]`; as they differ in size. Unlike Verilog, Cryptol will not "pad" things implicitly, and I think Cryptol is definitely doing the right thing here. Verilog programmers can chime in with countless bugs they had due to implicit casting.

All such casting in Cryptol has to be explicit.

The typical way to deal with this situation in Cryptol is to use the polymorphic constant `zero`:

```
Cryptol> :t zero
zero : {a} (Zero a) => a
```

The value `zero` inhabits all types (you can ignore the `Zero` constraint for now), and as you can imagine is the "right" padding value in this case. So, you'd define your function as:

```
Cryptol> let test(x:[2], y:[8]) = (zero#x)^y
Cryptol> :t test
test : ([2], [8]) -> [8]
```

And use it like this:

```
Cryptol> test (1, 5)
0x04
```

And if you wanted to pad on the right for some reason, you'd do:

```
Cryptol> let test(x:[2], y:[8]) = (x#zero)^y
Cryptol> test(1,5)
0x45
```

This way, everything is explicit and you don't have to know all the magical rules about how things get padded to become the right size.

If you want to get real fancy, then you can do:

```
Cryptol> let test(x, y) = (zero#x)^(zero#y)
Cryptol> :t test
test : {n, m, i, j, a} (Logic a, Zero a, m + i == n + j, fin n,
                        fin m) =>
         ([i]a, [j]a) -> [m + i]a
```

Now, that type looks a bit scary; but essentially it's telling you that you can give it any sized arguments, and it would be valid for any other size, so long as the new size is larger than the maximum of the two you've given. Of course, this inferred size is way more polymorphic then you probably cared for; so you can give it something more readable:

```
test : {m, n} (fin m, fin n) => [m] -> [n] -> [max m n]
test x y = (zero#x) ^ (zero#y)
```

I believe this captures your intent perfectly. Note how cryptol will make sure your inputs are finite, and you get the maximum of the two sizes given.

Getting back to your example, Cryptol is telling you that to multiply by 16 you need at least 5 bits, and thus `2>=5` is not satisfiable. This is a bit cryptic, but arises from the use of literals which are polymorphically typed. You can use the `zero` trick to address the issue in the same way as before:

```
Cryptol> let shift (v, s:[2]) = v >>> ((zero#s)*16+8)
[warning] at <interactive>:1:32--1:38:
  Defaulting type argument 'front' of '(#)' to 3
```

But note how cryptol is warning you about the type of `zero` that's used there, since the type of `>>>` is polymorphic enough to allow different size shifts/rotates:

```
Cryptol> :t (>>>)
(>>>) : {n, ix, a} (fin n, fin ix) => [n]a -> [ix] -> [n]a
```

In these cases, Cryptol will pick the smallest possible size to default to by looking at the expressions. Unfortunately, it does the wrong thing here. By picking size `3` for `zero`, you'll have a `5` bit shift, but your expression can produce the maximum value of `3*16+8=56`, which requires at least 6 bits to represent. Note that Cryptol only uses the minimum size required to handle the multiplication there, and does not care about overflows! This is why it's important to pay attention to such warnings.

To be clear: Cryptol did the *right* thing per the language rules on how type inference works, but it ended up picking a size that is just too small for what you wanted to do.

So, you should write your `shift` as follows:

```
Cryptol> let shift (v, s:[2]) = v >>> (((zero:[4])#s)*16+8)
Cryptol> :t shift
shift : {n, a} (fin n) => ([n]a, [2]) -> [n]a
```

The important thing here is to make sure the expression `s*16+8` will fit in the final result, and since `s` is only 2 bits wide the largest value will be `56` as discussed above, which needs at least 6-bits to represent. This is why I chose `[4]` as the size of `zero`.

The moral of the story here is that you should always be explicit about the sizes of your bitvectors, and Cryptol will give you the right framework to express your constraints in a polymorphic way to allow for code reuse without ambiguity, avoiding many of the pitfalls of Verilog and other similar languages.